Error Handling in FastEndpoints does not work
I am trying to handle errors globally in my project. I hate the idea to have try-catch in each endpoint.
I have the following endpoint for testing:
public sealed class Endpoint(SepukuDbContext dbContext, IJwtTokenService jwtTokenService, IUserAuthorizationService userAuthorizationService) : Endpoint<Request>
{
    public override async Task HandleAsync(Request req, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var user = await dbContext.Users.Where(x => x.Email == req.Email).Select(x => x).SingleOrDefaultAsync(ct);

        if (user is null)
        {
            ThrowError("The supplied credentials are invalid!");
            return;
        }

        if (userAuthorizationService.IsAuthorized(user, req.Password))
        {
            await SendAsync(
                    new
                    {
                        Username = user.Name,
                        Token = jwtTokenService.GetToken(user),
                    });
        }
        else
        {
            ThrowError("The supplied credentials are invalid!");
        }
    }
}

To test the error handling, jwtTokenService.GetToken(user) throws InvalidDataException.
However, the endpoints returns 200 Response.Ok. Why?
I added app.UseDefaultExceptionHandler() for global error handling, but it did not help.

First of all, I tried equivalent code with throwing exception inside SendAsync and it correctly returns 500 ISE error HTTP response. So my first suspicion would be that exception is not being thrown, that's why you get still 200 OK response.
Nevertheless, here's correct setup of error handling in ASP.NET app (also when working with FastEndpoint):
// Our exception handler
public class ExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return ValueTask.FromResult(true); // if exception is handled, false if not
    }
}

And application setup:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services.AddFastEndpoints();

// Register our exception handler
builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<ExceptionHandler>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Use exception handling middleware
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
app.UseFastEndpoints();

app.Run();

Reference: Handle errors in ASP.NET Core
